# The rest syntax is not working in Chrome 49

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using Windows XP with Chrome 49.0.2623.75(64 bit) because of some dependency reason. I am using rest operator from ECMAScript but it is giving error as "Uncaught syntaxerror: Unexpected token ..." This code is working in latest Chrome version. Is there a way or dependency to run below code for Chrome 49. My code is written below.

```
this.dict = this.header.reduce((obj, k, i) => ({...obj, [k]: this.class[i] }), {})
```

Comment: You will need to use a transpiler. Older browsers just don't support language features that have been specified in 2018.

Comment: For reference, Chrome 49 was released 2016-03-02

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use the ES6 "spread" operator (`...`) native in an unsupported browser. There is no 1:1 polyfill (like for something like an Array.prototype method).

Your options include:

1. Using a bundler tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) combined with [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to parse the ES6 and output your-browser-client-compliant ES5.
2. Manually swap out the "spread" operator with usages of "apply." See [this article](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/using-apply-to-emulate-javascripts-upcoming-spread-operator.html) as an example. Also, [the MDN page on the rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_function_calls) has an example of how to swap uses of "apply" for the "spread" operator, you can reverse those examples manually.

Additional background:

The "rest/spread" operator is a "[syntactic sugar](https://www.quora.com/What-is-syntactic-sugar-in-programming-languages)" tool added in ES6 / ES2015 ([as discussed in this article](https://bytearcher.com/articles/es6-vs-es2015-name/), that version of JavaScript is referred to by both names). Its naming is mildly confusing, as sometimes it is referred to by either the "[rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)" or as "[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)." "Spread Syntax" and "Spread Operator" are probably the most recognizable way to refer to this operator, as it includes all use-cases, whereas "rest parameter" typically only refers to the use case of using `...` within the parameters passed to a function.

Comment: To be clear (and to help people who may want to search further), this is actually a use of the spread syntax, not the rest syntax.

Comment: And rest/spread for object literals has not been part of ES6 (2015) but of ES2018.

Comment: Spread operator / rest parameters appear to be added in ES2015 according to this article: https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_overviews.html#overview-entry-parameter-handling

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the feedback, added clarifying research

Comment: @CalebJay Not for objects literals. Read the MDN article you linked.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the code you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
this.dict = this.header.reduce((obj, k, i) => Object.assign(obj, { [k]: this.class[i] }), {})
```

[Browser compatability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility)